# iTunes music Library empty

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, music, apple-music

[image]

I was listening to music a couple of minutes ago, and launched music, and noticed that everything was gone. I have tried respringing multiple times and quitting and relaunching mail, but it keeps telling me that there is nothing in my library. Music that I owned was gone, and so was all of my apple music.

iOS 10.3.3, jailbroken, haven't checked my laptop to see if this is happening there.

My music was really essential to me, is there any way to get it all back?

Answer (score 1):

I've had success in the past using [iExplorer](https://macroplant.com/iexplorer) to view files in an iOS file system and iTunes backups. I will add as a caveat that these were native iOS devices and not jailbroken, so your mileage may vary.

High level: install iExplorer on your computer, run it, connect the affected device, unlock it as required, and see what files it finds using the various menus on the left column.